# Highlighted Indent Guides VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

How to change like the images above?

Comment: Where did you get the image from?  Which editor?  I like those indent guides.

Comment: same editor, visual studio code

Comment: Which extension then?  That isn't built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Bracket Pair Colorizer](https://github.com/CoenraadS/Bracket-Pair-Colorizer-2) extension, it will generate colorized brackets like this :

[image: highlight]

Comment: how about something like this but for html tags ?